# Android Text view position with custom buttons in the layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I've the following layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@color/all_white"
    android:gravity="center">

    <Button android:id="@+id/mq_categories" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:text="Browse Quiz Categories" android:textColor="#EDFF99"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_button" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/mq_random" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:text="Enter Random Quiz" android:textColor="#EDFF99"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_button" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/mq_profile" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:text="My Profile" android:textColor="#EDFF99"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

which gives the output as

[image]

**Now I need to add a welcome text at the top section of the screen**

When I added the text view like this, only welcome text is displayed and no buttons and no scroll

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@color/all_white"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/mg_userinfo" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:text="Welcome"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <Button android:id="@+id/mq_categories" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:text="Browse Quiz Categories" android:textColor="#EDFF99"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_button" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/mq_random" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:text="Enter Random Quiz" android:textColor="#EDFF99"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_button" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/mq_profile" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:text="My Profile" android:textColor="#EDFF99"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_button" />


</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

When tried below lay out welcome text is displayed at the bottom of the buttons, but buttons got shifted to the top of the screen

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@color/all_white"
    android:gravity="center">

    <Button android:id="@+id/mq_categories" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:text="Browse Quiz Categories" android:textColor="#EDFF99"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_button" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/mq_random" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:text="Enter Random Quiz" android:textColor="#EDFF99"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_button" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/mq_profile" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:text="My Profile" android:textColor="#EDFF99"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_button" />

    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/mg_userinfo" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:text="Welcome"
        android:gravity="center" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

**How can I need to add a welcome text at the top section of the screen with button on the center?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the following property of textview:

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

And put your textview above the buttons.

Answer (score 1):

if you use

> android:layout_height="fill_parent"

android will fill to full screen.
you can use

> android:layout_height="20DIP"

or

> android:layout_height="20px"

Comment: The use of px is not encouraged. It doesn't scale properly on the devices of varying screen densities. Always use dip or dp (both are same).